# Solving "Operation aborted: max-element-depth constraint violated" error by MS Word

Tags: ms-word

This error is given by MS Word 2013 Windows (8 and 10) and a similar error message by Mac (10.10) Office 2011. Both packages can "recover" contents. Unless opened by same package error happens after recovery even when both machines run same version of word (Windows 8 & Windows 10 in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found is best described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpQMZH9mYu0) video. The steps are as follows:

1. Open the .docx archive using 7zip or similar package without extracting the contents.
2. Find the webSettings.xml file in the word/ directory within the archive and delete it.
   [image: word/webSettings.xml file]
3. Close the archive without changing anything else.

Done.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well.

Essentially the same solution found [elsewhere](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/423360a6-a579-4043-abf5-5d0b1f1c31c7/solvederror-opening-large-documents-created-in-word-2010-in-word-2013?forum=word)

Answer (score -1):

if you've got [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) installed and any need to keep fixing several files, you could simply make this batch file, and drag and drop the "corrupted" `.docx` file into it:

```
C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe d $1 word/webSettings.xml
```

feel free to [adapt it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881845/creating-a-batch-file-that-can-process-a-drag-and-drop-of-multiple-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) to accept multiple files as needed.