# Creating a Batch File that can Process a Drag and Drop of Multiple Files

Tags: windows, batch-file, drag-and-drop, tshark

I am trying to process several files by running them through a batch file. I want the batch file to be able to take all the files its given (aka dumped; or dragged and dropped) and process them.

Currently I can process the files individually with the following batch command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -r %1 -Y "filter" -o "uat:user_dlts:\"User 8 (DLT=155)\",\"pxt\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -o "gui.column.format:\"Info\",\"%%i\""> %1".filter.txt"
```

I am looking to do the same thing as above, but with the ability to simply drag and drop the files onto the batch file to be processed.

For those confused about the above batch file:

-r Reads the input file, whose full file address (including extension) is captured by %1

-Y Filters out certain parts of the dragged & dropped file

-o Sets preferences (defined by stuff in the ""s) for running the executable: tshark.exe

- > redirects the results to stdout

- %1".filter.txt" outputs the results to a new file called "draggedfilename.filter.txt"

Please refrain from using this code anywhere else except helping me with this code (due to the application it is being used for). I changed several flags in this version of the code for privacy sake.
Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Don't do this. Drag&drop isn't implemented correctly in explorer: the command line arguments are broken on special characters (like  `&`) that are valid in quoted file names (explorer misses to quote them). Better invest your time in a solution with [`[vbscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) that is mostly available where `.bat` and `.cmd` is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file Copy using %1 for drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786623/batch-file-copy-using-1-for-drag-and-drop)

Comment: I highly recommend this answer from jeb https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192427/4172159
It works perfectly for files with & and ! characters in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go for a loop using `goto` and `shift` like this (see `rem` comments for details):

```
:LOOP
rem check first argument whether it is empty and quit loop in case;
rem `%1` is the argument as is; `%~1` removes surrounding quotes;
rem `"%~1"` therefore ensures that the argument is always enclosed within quotes:
if "%~1"=="" goto :END
rem the argument is passed over to the command to execute (`"%~1"`):
"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -r "%~1" -Y "filter" -o "uat:user_dlts:\"User 8 (DLT=155)\",\"pxt\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -o "gui.column.format:\"Info\",\"%%i\""> "%~1.filter.txt"
rem `shift` makes the second argument (`%2`) to be the first (`%1`), the third (`%3`) to be the second (`%2`),...:
shift
rem go back to top:
goto :LOOP
:END
```

Comment: This method worked and the %%a & %* didn't. Thanks for the help. The comments also helped and clarified what I needed and what was happening. I will probably include better versions of the rems in my version for programming reference later if we need to make more batch files like this.

Comment: This answer does not work on any file names that contain a & ampersand and no spaces.  For example  This&that.txt  Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: @JG1212, if you are typing such arguments in Command Prompt, use quotation (`"This&that.txt"`); if you are dragging-and-dropping (so there are no quotes since there is no _space_), follow [Squashman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881845/creating-a-batch-file-that-can-process-a-drag-and-drop-of-multiple-files/33882316#comment55532380_33882316)…

Comment: @aschipfl thanks.  I ended up using a revised answer from jeb here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192427/4172159  It works perfectly for both & and ! in file names.

Answer (score 7):

Use `%*` instead of `%1`.

**Example :**

```
@echo off 

for %%a in (%*) do  (
"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -r "%%a" -Y "filter" -o "uat:user_dlts:\"User 8 (DLT=155)\",\"pxt\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"" -o "gui.column.format:\"Info\",\"%%i\""> "%%a"".filter.txt"
)
```

Replace `%%i` with the right variable.

Comment: Just a few notes. Any files you drop onto the batch file will be quoted if they have spaces in the path. Also if you drop enough files onto the batch file that have really long paths you can exceed the line limit.  It is 4096 in XP and 8192 in Windows 7.  Also, any file names that have an ampersand in them without a space will not process correctly.   Another option to process all the arguments is too use SHIFT and then check if %1 is not empty and loop back to a label.  Here is a link to Jeb's take on how to do this a different way.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5370380/1417694

Comment: Didn't work in my system. Regarding %%i, that defines a variable within tshark that is used to filter out certain portions of the file I am dumping. %%i has no effect on the batch file since its in double quotes.

Comment: if you will use `set` inside loop, then  don't forget `!variable_name!` instead of `%variable_name%` and use *delayed expansion*.